# MySQL problem with query construction. Making columns from attributes

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, pivot

I have started working with MySQL database. I have to do the task of creating XML file using java from existing database. I`ve already done the XML structure and instert some data in document but i have a problem with getting  data from db. This problem is described below:

**products_extra_fields**

```
products_extra_fields_id | products_extra_fields_name
-------------------------|---------------------------
           1             |       cpu
           2             |       hdd
           3             |       diagonal
           4             |       gpu
```

**products**

```
products_id | products_name | products_quantity  
------------| --------------|-------------------
      1     |  product name |      123
      2     |  product name |      125
      3     |  product name |      12
      4     |  product name |      43
```

**products_to_products_extra_fields**

```
products_id  | products_extra_fields_id | products_extra_fields_value
-------------|--------------------------|---------------------------- 
      3      |            1             |             i7
      2      |            4             |           geforce
      2      |            1             |             i5
      3      |            3             |             15.6
```

Result of query should look like this or similar:

```
products_id | cpu | diagonal |   gpu   | ...
------------|-----|--------- |---------|----
     3      | i7  |   15.6   | geforce | 
...
...
```

Is there any simple way to get data like this? I have already joined some tables but i have too poor knowleadge to make query containing above result:

```
SELECT * FROM products p 
INNER JOIN products_description pd ON pd.products_id = p.products_id 
INNER JOIN products_to_categories ptc ON ptc.products_id = p.products_id 
INNER JOIN categories_description cd ON cd.categories_id = ptc.categories_id 
INNER JOIN manufacturers m ON p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id 
INNER JOIN products_availability_description pad ON pad.products_availability_id = p.products_availability_id 
INNER JOIN products_availability pa ON pa.products_availability_id = pad.products_availability_id 
WHERE p.products_quantity > 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    pf.products_id,
    max(case when f.products_extra_fields_name = 'cpu'      then pf.products_extra_fields_value end) cpu,
    max(case when f.products_extra_fields_name = 'diagonal' then pf.products_extra_fields_value end) diagonal,
    max(case when f.products_extra_fields_name = 'gpu'      then pf.products_extra_fields_value end) gpu
from products_to_products_extra_fields pf
inner join products_extra_fields f 
    on e.products_extra_fields_id  = pf.products_extra_fields_id 
group by pf.products_id
```

Note that for this result, you don't need to bring the `products` table; if you need columns from that table (like the name of the product), you can bring it with one more `join`.

Unrelated note: you should not put the table name in the column name; this requires more typing, makes the query much more verbose, and does not add much valuable information (using table identifiers, we know already which column comes from which table).